# SQL - Group by Date prevent duplicates

Tags: sql, ssms, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a running total by month and year of total employees per month.

I have the following:

- **Date:**
  TCTIMESTAP if null GOLIVEDATE. TCTIME from EE & GOLIVEDATE from SC.
- **EMPLOYEESTATUS ID:**
  The ID indicates the status that I need to include in the count.

I only want to group the counts by **Date**

Take this example table:

**Date| CompanyId | Total_Employees**
30 / 09 / 2021 76 169
30 / 09 / 2021 79 285
31 / 08 / 2021 79 280
31 / 08 / 2021 76 162
31 / 07 / 2021 79 272
31 / 07 / 2021 76 148
30 / 06 / 2021 79 266
30 / 06 / 2021 76 139

The expected results should be

**Date |    Total_Employees**
30/09/2021  454
31/08/2021  442
31/07/2021  420
30/06/2021  405

but if you remove **CompanyId** from the where clause to look at every client (about 2000) it multiplies the sum by however many times it appears in **EE**, **SC** , **RegisteredUserID**  and **EmployeeStatusID**

My code so far

```
Select
Dates2,
sum(TE) over (Order by Dates2)

from (

SELECT 
ISNULL(EOMONTH(ER.TCTimestamp),EOMONTH(SC.GoLiveDate)) as Dates2, 
EE.CompanyId, 
Name,
sum(case when EmployeeStatusId = '0' or EmployeeStatusId ='1' or EmployeeStatusId ='2' then 1 else 0 end) as TE 
from D.Employee EE
Inner  JOIN SuperAdmin.Customer AS SC on SC.CompanyId = EE.CompanyId  
Left Join D.RegisteredUser AS ER on EE.RegisteredUserId = ER.RegisteredUserId 

WHERE SC.CompanyId = 76 or SC.CompanyId = 79
GROUP BY
ISNULL(EOMONTH(ER.TCTimestamp),EOMONTH(SC.GoLiveDate)), 
EE.CompanyId, 
Name) as A


GROUP BY Dates2, te


order by Dates2 desc
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: re-wrote the question let me know if this adds more clarity

Comment: Please include the clear table/column definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a test case.  Please update this with data that shows the behavior you don't like.  Indicate the expected result:

[Working Test Case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32b4d0558e89a799f500a07f3fb5528a)

There really isn't enough detail about the meaning of the columns of interest.  But, assuming you really want to count these cases per day, the following corrects the `GROUP BY` logic to aggregate per day, and adjusts the `SUM` logic accordingly:

Here's another guess, if you really wanted to count the `TE` groups separately and then aggregate those per date before performing the running `SUM` per date.  Please excuse any typos.  I don't have your tables for testing.

Guess 2:

```
SELECT Dates2
     , SUM(SUM(TE2)) OVER (Order by Dates2)
  FROM (
         SELECT Dates2
              , SUM(TE) AS TE2
           FROM (
                  SELECT ISNULL(EOMONTH(ER.TCTimestamp), EOMONTH(SC.GoLiveDate)) AS Dates2
                       , EE.CompanyId
                       , Name
                       , SUM(CASE WHEN EmployeeStatusId IN ('0', '1', '2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TE
                    FROM D.Employee EE
                    JOIN SuperAdmin.Customer   AS SC
                      ON SC.CompanyId = EE.CompanyId
                    LEFT JOIN D.RegisteredUser AS ER
                      ON EE.RegisteredUserId = ER.RegisteredUserId
                   WHERE SC.CompanyId IN (76, 79)
                   GROUP BY ISNULL(EOMONTH(ER.TCTimestamp), EOMONTH(SC.GoLiveDate))
                          , EE.CompanyId
                          , Name
                ) AS A
          GROUP BY Dates2, TE
       ) AS t1
 GROUP BY Dates2
 ORDER BY Dates2 desc
;
```

Guess 1:

```
SELECT Dates2
     , SUM(SUM(TE)) OVER (Order by Dates2)
  FROM (
         SELECT ISNULL(EOMONTH(ER.TCTimestamp), EOMONTH(SC.GoLiveDate)) AS Dates2
              , EE.CompanyId
              , Name
              , SUM(CASE WHEN EmployeeStatusId IN ('0', '1', '2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TE
           FROM D.Employee EE
           JOIN SuperAdmin.Customer   AS SC
             ON SC.CompanyId = EE.CompanyId
           LEFT JOIN D.RegisteredUser AS ER
             ON EE.RegisteredUserId = ER.RegisteredUserId
          WHERE SC.CompanyId IN (76, 79)
          GROUP BY ISNULL(EOMONTH(ER.TCTimestamp), EOMONTH(SC.GoLiveDate))
                 , EE.CompanyId
                 , Name
       ) AS A
 GROUP BY Dates2
 ORDER BY Dates2 desc
;
```

If this isn't exactly what you wanted, please provide more detail about the meaning of the status column and date/timestamp columns.

Plus, there's one other detail that might need to be addressed.  Can an active customer become inactive?

Comment: re-werote the question to add more clarity (hopefully). Just as an FYI you answer works to an extent. The only issue I had when i remove the where clause it multiples the sum by however many times the companyId appears in the other tables and yes the active can be come inactive but we dont record the date this happens :( so not to bothered

Comment: @Fazza Review the result now.  I addressed those duplicates with the correct `GROUP BY`, which also corrected the window function result.  I could post a runnable test case, but it would be better if you can show the behavior with your own test case, using both your SQL and the solution I proposed, to clarify the issue.

Comment: This worked it also helped clean up on a few more parts of my script making it less messy e.g. the CASE WHEN using IN rather than using OR